# Different ways to disable radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What are the different ways to disable a radio button.

I tried the example below but not working in my system with my environment set up. Its working if I am trying on notepad without environment. Is there any other ways?

```
var status = 'A';
   $("input[type=radio][value=" + status + "]").attr("disabled",true);
```

Comment: From the jQuery API documentation: "The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method". Also see this tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to just use disabled in HTML find your [UPDATED CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/h8kdfmjs/3/)

```
    <div id="cosProfile">CoS Profile</div>
    <span class="icon-information"></span>
<div class="form-field" data-radio id="cosRadioBtns">
    <span id="radio_prdefined"><input type="radio" name="CosProfile" data-radio 
 value="predefined" checked="checked" disabled/></span>
        <label id="cos_predefined">Predefined Profile</label>
    <span id="radio_custom"><input type="radio" name="CosProfile" data-radio 
value="custom" disabled/></span>
        <label id="cos_custom">Custom Profile</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3885720, be sure to mark helpful answers as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=radio][value=" + status + "]").prop("disabled",true);
```

Comment: @linurb.Its not working as well.

Comment: Ok, then I guess you need to provide more context.

Comment: You can also disable in plain HTML or CSS what's your intent?

Comment: @linurb. Here is the fiddle of my code. http://jsfiddle.net/h8kdfmjs/1/

Comment: Have you tried .prop("disabled", "disabled"); instead?

Comment: @user3362232. I tried putting disabled="disabled" in my html radio button input tag, but didn't work.

Comment: @DanielSanchez. I tried its not working.

Comment: can you update your fiddle, its not even referencing jQuery, nor any other libraries you are trying to use.

Comment: There's a lot of undefined stuff in your fiddle (such as "av" and the function "radio()"). If you strip out everthing but the code for disabling it works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/h8kdfmjs/4/